# jquery appendTo function not working inside ajax success function

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, append

I'm trying to fetch some data using jQuery ajax method. here is my code:

```
$('body').on('click','.showSlots', function() {
var screen_Id = $(this).attr('id');
//alert(screen_Id);

$.ajax({
    url:base_url+'admin/movies/getScreenSlots',
    type:'post',
    data: {screen_Id:screen_Id},
    success: function(result)
    {   

      result = $.parseJSON(result);
      //$('.screenList1,.screenList12').empty();   
      $.each(result, function( key, element )
      {

                    $('<tr class="screenList1"><td><input required name="slotName" type="text" placeholder="enter slot"><input name="screen_id1" required type="hidden" value="'+element.screen_id+'" class="screen_ids1"></td><td><input required name="movieName" type="text" placeholder="Movie Name"></td><td><input required name="rate" type="text" placeholder="rate"></td></tr>').appendTo($(this).closest('table'));
        });

      }
   });
});
```

Data successfully getting from DB. and jquery 'each' function working well. but 'appendTo' function not working. Tried in many browser. But same problem in all. please help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your html as well?

Comment: When you refer to 'this' inside the .each function it reference the current item in the array you are looping through.

Comment: Hi @Sean Wessell That was issue!!. Problem is now fixed, Thank you very much Sean Wessell..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` does not refer to what you think it does.

You should find the table element outside the ajax call, and save to a variable:

```
$('body').on('click','.showSlots', function() {

    var screen_Id = $(this).attr('id');
    var table = $(this).closest('table');

    $.ajax({
        url:base_url+'admin/movies/getScreenSlots',
        type:'post',
        data: {screen_Id:screen_Id},
        success: function(result){   

          result = $.parseJSON(result); 
          $.each(result, function( key, element ){
              $('...your html...').appendTo(table);
           });

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your implementation is current element context `this` does't refer to clicked `showSlots` in the success handler.

Store the reference of the table in a variable and use it while appending html.

```
$('body').on('click', '.showSlots', function() {
    var table= $(this).closest('table'); //Store the reference
    $.ajax({
        success: function(result) {                
            $.each(result, function(key, element) { 
                $('<tr ></tr>').appendTo(table); //Use it
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
appendTo($(this).closest('table'));

to 

appendTo($('.showSlots').closest('table'));
```

because $(this) do not refers to '.showSlots' as you are in another function of ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

you should write your code like this, save the current element in a varable called "obj", then add the new created row using that variable

```
$('body').on('click','.showSlots', function() {
var screen_Id = $(this).attr('id');
var obj=$(this);
$.ajax({
    url:base_url+'admin/movies/getScreenSlots',
    type:'post',
    data: {screen_Id:screen_Id},
    success: function(result)
    {   
         result = $.parseJSON(result); 
         $.each(result, function( key, element )
         {
              $('<tr class="screenList1"><td><input required name="slotName" type="text" placeholder="enter slot"><input name="screen_id1" required type="hidden" value="'+element.screen_id+'" class="screen_ids1"></td><td><input required name="movieName" type="text" placeholder="Movie Name"></td><td><input required name="rate" type="text" placeholder="rate"></td></tr>').appendTo($(obj).closest('table'));
    });

  }
```

});
});

Comment: Please remember to add a commentary regarding what you have changed / what should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take reference of object in some variable and then use it in the each loop. You can do it like folloing :-

```
$('body').on('click','.showSlots', function() {
var screen_Id = $(this).attr('id');
$this = $(this);
//alert(screen_Id);

$.ajax({
    url:base_url+'admin/movies/getScreenSlots',
    type:'post',
    data: {screen_Id:screen_Id},
    success: function(result)
    {   

      result = $.parseJSON(result);
      //$('.screenList1,.screenList12').empty();   
      $.each(result, function( key, element )
      {

                    $('<tr class="screenList1"><td><input required name="slotName" type="text" placeholder="enter slot"><input name="screen_id1" required type="hidden" value="'+element.screen_id+'" class="screen_ids1"></td><td><input required name="movieName" type="text" placeholder="Movie Name"></td><td><input required name="rate" type="text" placeholder="rate"></td></tr>').appendTo($this.closest('table'));
        });
      }
   });
});
```

It may helpful.

Comment: I have store the reference of $(this) in variable and then use that in the success part of the AJAX within the each loop.

Comment: Can you please try this?

Comment: @user3706231 I think you just forgot about that small mistake.